# run uwsgi with zerorpc

Tags: python, pyramid, zeromq, gevent

I've some problem with run uwsgi.

I run application(Pyramid with zerorpc, gevent) in uwsgi. And some requests fails.
Python writes this error:

Assertion failed: ok (bundled/zeromq/src/mailbox.cpp:79)
Aborted
uWSGI worker 1 screams: UAAAAAAH my master disconnected: i will kill myself !!!

Why there might be such a problem?

uwsgi config:

```
[uwsgi]
socket = /tmp/sock.sock
chmod-socket = 666
master = true
processes = 1
vacuum = true
```

i run so:
uwsgi --ini-paste development.ini

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the whole zeromq magic is managed by a background thread. A property of threads is that they "disappear" after fork(), so zeromq will not work in your uWSGI worker. Just add

lazy-apps = true

in your uWSGI options to load zeromq (read: your app) after each fork()

Comment: Thank you very much. Really works. Could you give a link to more information on this feature?